# implementing email service in my code

Tags: java, jsp, email, jakarta-mail

i have been trying to implement the following servlet code to implement email facility but i am constanly getting error with this code. pls have a look at it...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

public class email extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String to="amanmaheshwari25@gmail.com"; //emailID at which the mail is send

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Session session=null;

    try{
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

       session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
       new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return new PasswordAuthentication("cconatus.2011@gmail.com","password");//change accordingly
       }
      });}
        catch(Exception e)
        {out.println("error234");}
      try {
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("ccnatus.2011@gmail.com"));//change accordingly
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
       message.setSubject("Pls find the message inside");
       String dd = "hey";
       message.setText(dd);

       //send message
       Transport.send(message);
       out.println("success");
           } 
      catch(Exception e)
            {out.println("error");}
      finally {            
                out.close();
            }
        }
```

the output that i'm getting is :
error i.e from the last catch block
pls give some suggestions regarding this asap.

Comment: Can you post the Stacktrace?

Comment: To start, instead of `out.println("error");` why don't you output the stacktrace?

Comment: @PeterRader the stack trace is as follows :
'javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)'

Answer (score 1):

Here are the properties that worked for me :

> mail.transport.protocol = smtp
>
> mail.smtp.host = smtp.gmail.com
>
> mail.smtp.auth = true
>
> mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
>
> mail.smtp.port = 587

Comment: still not able to send mail by these properties..... i used it 2 days earlier and it was working fine..... dnt know what has happened now..... could you pls send me ur **web.xml** file of ur project in which u implemented it.

Comment: could u pls send me the **web.xml** file of ur project where u hav implemented these settings and that **servlet file** also where u hav written this code...... Pls :)

Comment: @aman I can't send you that code, since it's not open source. I did compare your code to mine, and they look very similar. Beside the difference in the properties, the only difference I found is that you use message.setText and I use message.setContent. I'm not sure what you are expecting to find in the web.xml.

Comment: i actually need to find out the **value of the port no.** that have been set in web.xml file is same as that have been setted in the code above or there is any change in it. 
'<param-name>port</param-name>
  <param-value>25</param-value></context-param> <context-param><param-name>port</param-name> <param-value>465</param-value></context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>user</param-name>
        <param-value>YOUR_EMAIL</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>pass</param-name>
        <param-value>YOUR_PASSWORD</param-value>
    </context-param>'

Comment: why the value of the port no have been set twice in it. and why the value of user and password is not same as mentioned in the code 

'return new PasswordAuthentication("**cconatus.2011@gmail.com","password**");'

Comment: @aman I only set the port number once, in the `mail.smtp.port` property. I don't set the port number in web.xml, I set it just in the code (587 works for me). And I don't understand what you mean about user and password not being the same. The only parameters that matter are the ones that you use set in the code (in the `props.put` calls). In my code they are read from a configuration file, but they are defined once.